# Android wear packaging and distribution

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, hockeyapp, android-wear-2.0

I'm on my way to upgrade from Wear1.x to wear 2.x. Learnt that wear 2.x apps are no more embedded with companion phone app. So, I decided to generate a new apk for Android wear.

Now, I have to test this wear apk release version. We use hockey app for build distribution and I am wondering the way to distribute wear app. I couldn't find any documentation for wear distribution by hockey app.

I'm not only specifically looking for a solution around hockey app. I'm more interested what are the ways to distribute android wear builds before publishing it to play-store release channels. Can anyone please guide me?

Any insights much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in a new feature [just released](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/03/20/google-play-lets-developers-set-internal-test-channel-100-trusted-users-paid-apps-free/) by Google Play (as of Google I/O 2018). It's called an ["Internal Test channel"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213)

It lets you send a new version of your app in seconds to up to 100 test users, using the same infrastructure as Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

The common option would always be to create [test users before release](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213). Aside from your Hockey app, you can try [distributing through email](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/#publishing-email) or [releasing through a website](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/#publishing-website).

Comment: We do release to play store beta testers after build is ready after testing. I haven't used 'Internal test' option in play store yet. Is this targeted for providing builds to internal tester? I do normally prefer using email or website as last resort.